# Linear Interpolation. How to implement this algorithm in C ? (Python version is given)

Tags: python, c, algorithm, math, signal-processing

There exists one very good linear interpolation method. It performs linear interpolation requiring **at most one multiply per output sample**. I found its description in a third edition of Understanding DSP by Lyons. This method involves a special hold buffer. Given a number of samples to be inserted between any two input samples, it produces output points using linear interpolation. Here, I have rewritten this algorithm using Python:

```
temp1, temp2 = 0, 0
iL = 1.0 / L
for i in x:
   hold = [i-temp1] * L
   temp1 = i
   for j in hold:
      temp2 += j
      y.append(temp2 *iL)
```

where x contains input samples, L is a number of points to be inserted, y will contain output samples.

My question is **how to implement such algorithm in ANSI C in a most effective way**, e.g. is it possible to avoid the second loop?

NOTE: presented Python code is just to understand how this algorithm works.

UPDATE: here is an example how it works in Python:

```
x=[]
y=[]
hold=[]
num_points=20
points_inbetween = 2

temp1,temp2=0,0

for i in range(num_points):
   x.append( sin(i*2.0*pi * 0.1) )

L = points_inbetween
iL = 1.0/L
for i in x:
   hold = [i-temp1] * L
   temp1 = i
   for j in hold:
      temp2 += j
      y.append(temp2 * iL)
```

Let's say x=[.... 10, 20, 30 ....]. Then, if L=1, it will produce [... 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 ...]

Comment: If you just want to implement it in C for performance, but still use it from Python, I recommend [Cython](http://www.cython.org/).

Comment: presented Python code is just to understand how this algorithm works

Comment: It's easier to understand how an algorithm works if you use meaningful variable names.

Comment: @Lennart: Have updated. Now should be easy to understand

Comment: OK, I made a much simpler interpolating algorithm, that skips a lot of unneeded things.

Comment: Have you run your updated sample?  I just tried with `x=[0,10,20,30,40]` and `L=1`.  The result `y` was not what you say it will be...

Comment: @mtrw: yes, I have tested it and it does work. Try example I gave with sin() function and plot data. For the very first samples the result can be wrong (it's however normal for many pipeline DSP methods).

Comment: `Let's say x=[.... 10, 20, 30 ....]. Then, if L=1, it will produce [... 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 ...]` - not true.

Comment: It does work, except that his version will have L repeats of the first value in the beginning of the output.

Comment: Is there an online reference to the algorithm? Also, avoiding multiplications sounds like an optimization of the '80-ies...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Interpolation in the sense of "signal sample rate increase"

... or i call it, "upsampling" (wrong term, probably. disclaimer: i have not read Lyons'). I just had to understand what the code does and then re-write it for readability. As given it has couple of problems:

a) it is inefficient - two loops is ok but it does multiplication for every single output item; also it uses intermediary lists(`hold`), generates result with `append` (small beer)

b) it interpolates wrong the first interval; it generates fake data in front of the first element. Say we have multiplier=5 and seq=[20,30] - it will generate [0,4,8,12,16,20,22,24,28,30] instead of [20,22,24,26,28,30].

So here is the algorithm in form of a generator:

```
def upsampler(seq, multiplier):
    if seq:
        step = 1.0 / multiplier
        y0 = seq[0];
        yield y0
        for y in seq[1:]:
            dY = (y-y0) * step
            for i in range(multiplier-1):
                y0 += dY;
                yield y0
            y0 = y;
            yield y0
```

Ok and now for some tests:

```
>>> list(upsampler([], 3))  # this is just the same as [Y for Y in upsampler([], 3)]
[]
>>> list(upsampler([1], 3))
[1]
>>> list(upsampler([1,2], 3))
[1, 1.3333333333333333, 1.6666666666666665, 2]
>>> from math import sin, pi
>>> seq = [sin(2.0*pi * i/10) for i in range(20)]
>>> seq
[0.0, 0.58778525229247314, 0.95105651629515353, 0.95105651629515364, 0.58778525229247325, 1.2246063538223773e-016, -0.58778525229247303, -0.95105651629515353, -0.95105651629515364, -0.58778525229247336, -2.4492127076447545e-016, 0.58778525229247214, 0.95105651629515353, 0.95105651629515364, 0.58778525229247336, 3.6738190614671318e-016, -0.5877852522924728, -0.95105651629515342, -0.95105651629515375, -0.58778525229247347]
>>> list(upsampler(seq, 2))
[0.0, 0.29389262614623657, 0.58778525229247314, 0.76942088429381328, 0.95105651629515353, 0.95105651629515364, 0.95105651629515364, 0.7694208842938135, 0.58778525229247325, 0.29389262614623668, 1.2246063538223773e-016, -0.29389262614623646, -0.58778525229247303, -0.76942088429381328, -0.95105651629515353, -0.95105651629515364, -0.95105651629515364, -0.7694208842938135, -0.58778525229247336, -0.29389262614623679, -2.4492127076447545e-016, 0.29389262614623596, 0.58778525229247214, 0.76942088429381283, 0.95105651629515353, 0.95105651629515364, 0.95105651629515364, 0.7694208842938135, 0.58778525229247336, 0.29389262614623685, 3.6738190614671318e-016, -0.29389262614623618, -0.5877852522924728, -0.76942088429381306, -0.95105651629515342, -0.95105651629515364, -0.95105651629515375, -0.76942088429381361, -0.58778525229247347]
```

And here is my translation to C, fit into Kratz's fn template:

```
/**
 *
 * @param src caller supplied array with data
 * @param src_len len of src
 * @param steps to interpolate
 * @param dst output param will be filled with (src_len - 1) * steps + 1 samples
 */
float* linearInterpolation(float* src, int src_len, int steps, float* dst)
{
    float step, y0, dy;
    float *src_end;
    if (src_len > 0) {
        step = 1.0 / steps;
        for (src_end = src+src_len; *dst++ = y0 = *src++, src < src_end; ) {
            dY = (*src - y0) * step;
            for (int i=steps; i>0; i--) {
                *dst++ = y0 += dY;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note the C snippet is "typed but never compiled or run", so there might be syntax errors, off-by-1 errors etc. But overall the idea is there.

Comment: oh bummer, the bounty expired and only 1/2 got awarded. the other 25pts - phewt! - vanished from the stackoverflow realm.

Answer (score 2):

In that case I think you can avoid the second loop:

```
def interpolate2(x, L):
    new_list = []
    new_len = (len(x) - 1) * (L + 1)
    for i in range(0, new_len):
        step = i / (L + 1)
        substep = i % (L + 1)
        fr = x[step]
        to = x[step + 1]
        dy = float(to - fr) / float(L + 1)
        y = fr + (dy * substep)
        new_list.append(y)
    new_list.append(x[-1])
    return new_list

print interpolate2([10, 20, 30], 3)
```

you just calculate the member in the position you want directly. Though - that might not be the most efficient to do it. The only way to be sure is to compile it and see which one is faster.

Comment: No, you have copy-pasted a wrong sentence. I've spoken about what hold buffer makes. The complete algorithm produces linear-interpolation, not just repeating items. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Yeah, the number of calculations are not smaller this way. Looping in itself does not take significant time, so there is no need in avoiding it. Still, it should work.  +1 for showing alternate (if useless) solutions. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, your code is broken. L is not defined, and neither is y or x.

Once that is fixed, I run cython on the resulting code:

```
L = 1
temp1, temp2 = 0, 0
iL = 1.0 / L
y = []
x = range(5)
for i in x:
   hold = [i-temp1] * L
   temp1 = i
   for j in hold:
      temp2 += j
      y.append(temp2 *iL)
```

And that seemed to work. I haven't tried to compile it, though, and you can also improve the speed a lot by adding different optimizations.

"e.g. is it possible to avoid the second loop?"

If it is, then it's possible in Python too. And I don't see how, although I don't see why you would do it the way you do. First creating a list of L length of i-temp is completely pointless. Just loop L times:

```
L = 1
temp1, temp2 = 0, 0
iL = 1.0 / L
y = []
x = range(5)
for i in x:
   hold = i-temp1
   temp1 = i
   for j in range(L):
      temp2 += hold
      y.append(temp2 *iL)
```

It all seems overcomplicated for what you get out though. What are you trying to do, actually? Interpolate something? (Duh it says so in the title. Sorry about that.)

There are surely easier ways of interpolating.

Update, a much simplified interpolation function:

```
# A simple list, so it's easy to see that you interpolate.
indata = [float(x) for x in range(0, 110, 10)]
points_inbetween = 3

outdata = [indata[0]]

for point in indata[1:]: # All except the first
    step = (point - outdata[-1]) / (points_inbetween + 1)
    for i in range(points_inbetween):
        outdata.append(outdata[-1] + step)
```

I don't see a way to get rid of the inner loop, nor a reason for wanting to do so.
Converting it to C I'll leave up to someone else, or even better, Cython, as C is a great langauge of you want to talk to hardware, but otherwise just needlessly difficult.

Comment: @psihodelia: But i-temp1 does not make a list, so it will not be [10, 20, 10]. [i-temp1] will always be a list of one value only.

Comment: @Lennart, `* L` will cause the list to repeat.  `[1]*2` is `[1,1]`.  But yeah, I noticed the same thing, the repeated list doesn't really help express the algorithm.

Comment: @Lennart - I misunderstood your previous comment, I didn't realize you and I were pointing out the same thing.  Sorry.

Comment: Your new simplified interpolation is much much slower! You have a division operation in a loop. The purpose of the presented algorithm is to have only one multiplication per sample. Number of operations per sample is very important in signal processing.

Comment: @psihodelia - it's a division by a constant.  The compiler should see that and turn it into a multiply.  If profiling or checking the assembly shows it doesn't, then just declare a temp and precalculate it.  Anyway, this algorithm provides the correct result, which seems more important.

Comment: @mtrw: no, it required one division per sample, because dividend is always different

Comment: @phisodelia: Nonsense. It's not only simpler, it's also slightly faster. Don't claim things about speed before profiling. If that book told you anything else, I suggest you throw it out and get another one. And  you replace one division with one multiplication, which normally is not a significant improvement.

Comment: @psihodelia - The dividend is always `points_inbetween+1` which is constant.  Simply pre-calculate this as `fract = 1.0/(points_inbetween+1)` outside the loop, and change the first line of the outer loop to `step = fract*(point-outdata[-1])` and you're done.

Comment: @psihodelia @mtrw: Getting rid of the + by making the addition outside the loop makes a difference. Changing the division to a multiplication does not. (Yes, I timed it). It probably makes a difference in custom signal processors but with modern generic processors and compilers it's unlikely to make any difference. Remember, **always profile before optimization!**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the two loops.  You have to step over the samples in `x` to initialize the interpolator, not to mention copy their values into `y`, and you have to step over the output samples to fill in their values.  I suppose you could do one loop to copy `x` into the appropriate places in `y`, followed by another loop to use all the values from `y`, but that will still require some stepping logic.  Better to use the nested loop approach.

(And, as [Lennart Regebro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459930/linear-interpolation-how-to-translate-this-python-code-into-c/4460065#4460065) points out) As a side note, I don't see why you do `hold = [i-temp1] * L`.  Instead, why not do `hold = i-temp`, and then loop `for j in xrange(L):` and `temp2 += hold`?  This will use less memory but otherwise behave exactly the same.

Comment: Please don't pay big attention to Python code. I've just written it based on a visual LTI system diagram. It's only to understand how it does work. Yes, there is no need to use buffer in the code, but buffers are easy to place on the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Heres my try at a C implementation for your algorithm. Before trying to further optimize it id suggest you profile its performance with all compiler optimizations enabled.

```
/**
 *
 * @param src caller supplied array with data
 * @param src_len len of src
 * @param steps to interpolate
 * @param dst output param needs to be of size src_len * steps
 */
float* linearInterpolation(float* src, size_t src_len, size_t steps, float* dst)
{
  float* dst_ptr = dst;
  float* src_ptr = src;
  float stepIncrement = 1.0f / steps;
  float temp1 = 0.0f;
  float temp2 = 0.0f;
  float hold;
  size_t idx_src, idx_steps;
  for(idx_src = 0; idx_src < src_len; ++idx_src)
  {
    hold = *src_ptr - temp1;
    temp1 = *src_ptr;
    ++src_ptr;
    for(idx_steps = 0; idx_steps < steps; ++idx_steps)
    {
      temp2 += hold;
      *dst_ptr = temp2 * stepIncrement;
      ++dst_ptr;
    }
  }
}
```